# meteorjs: laika client and server test timout

Tags: tdd, meteor, laika

I'm trying out [laika](http://arunoda.github.io/laika/) test framework for meteor. The second example from the [homepage](http://arunoda.github.io/laika/) uses `observe()` and I think it is not observing correctly.

```
suite('Posts', function() {
    test('using both client and server', function(done, server, client) {
    server.eval(function() {
      Posts.find().observe({
        added: addedNewPost
      });
      function addedNewPost(post) {
        emit('post', post);
      }
    }).once('post', function(post) {
      assert.equal(post.title, 'hello title');
      done();
    });
    client.eval(function() {
      Posts.insert({title: 'hello title'});
    });
  });
});
```

I always get a timeout. Increasing the timeout period doesn't help. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong and I can't work out how to get any more verbose output. Peppering the tests with calls to console.log() gives nothing.

output:

```
1) Posts using both client and the server:
 Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded
  at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/laika/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:165:14)
  at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've had a similar issue with laika, with node 0.10.10. I switched to node 0.10.4, and the timeouts disappeared.

I don't know if your case is exactly the same as mine, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Yes laika has some issues with node version 0.10.8 to 0.10.10 - it is something with node-phantom module used by laika

Comment: I'm having the same problem with `node v0.10.24`. More info can be found under [laika issue #48](https://github.com/arunoda/laika/issues/48).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the mongodb is your bottleneck.

Start mongodb this way:

> mongod --smallfiles --noprealloc --nojournal

I was able to run the laika tests under the default 5000ms timeout.
However if you're running this on a slow computer, you can simple change the laika default timeout:

> laika -t 10000

In my experience, it has nothing to do with the version of nodejs. However there are some problems in mac os x version that set the cpu around 30% to 60%+ in idle.